# collapsible panel and delete button in a web application

Tags: web, accordion, deletion, collapsible-panels

I'm developing a web application and I need some advice on where to place  the delete button

Users can create, modify or delete items arranged as a list of vertically aligned elements. Each element is a collapsible panel and it can be expanded to reveal the setting under it. Here my two ideas on how to design the item opener and the delete button:

[image]

I need to place the delete button (which deletes the item). First option (the arrow) looks more user friendly and familiar but then I don't know where to palace the delete button. Second option has the delete button but it has the same emphasis as the menu button. What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: The first option *could* contain the buttons in the expanded area, but where would the second option contain the "expand" button?

Comment: In the second option the expand button is the "three dots button". But it could be the same as in the first option. I'm just experimenting with different icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expand button looks good to me where it is in your first option (the three dots icon is used for [menus](https://material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html#)). Some ideas:

- You could place additional actions inside the [expanded panel](https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#expansion-panels-behavior).

[image]

- Depending on the amount of items there user might want to remove at once, you could use a checkbox to [select the list items](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists-controls.html#lists-controls-usage) and the remove action button would appear in the top of the list.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(This last behaviour is explained in [Material design - Data Tables](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-tables-within-cards))

Comment: ok, CANCEL to me it's not clear. Does it delete the entire item? does it undo the changes on the fields and collapse the panel? Sounds more the latter

Comment: The image belongs to the link, it is not the same case. I just include it to *illustrate that action buttons can be placed inside of the panel*. This might be useful or not depending on the purpose of the panel and the importance of the action.

Comment: Ok.. please have a look at my own answer, I used the concept you suggested me (footer + actions). The emphasis in on the SAVE rather than the DELETE

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

[image]

Comment: In this case, "Save" appears if changes were made. But "Remove" should be there in any case. Also the two actions are different. Normally those should be opposite, something like "Save" "Don't save" (/"Cancel").

Comment: So where I could place the delete button?

Comment: Do you need to confirm or save the changes with a button (manually)?

Comment: I need an extra "delete" button somewhere which will delete the entire item, the entire panel (which is an item). The "save" button is fine. Confirmation is only required of the "delete button"

Comment: Check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFdg4.png). I would go for the Data table approach I commented in the answer. But probably someone will have a better suggestion.